# Placing maximum number of rooks

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching, bipartite

Problem:
I'm given a `NxN` chessboard with `M` cells with holes on it. I've to find maximum number of rooks that can be placed on it such that each row or column has equal number of rooks on it. (Note that the rooks may attack each other)

I've tried to model this by assuming each row and column to be a node. Add an edge (of capacity 1) between node corresponding to `r_i` and node corresponding to `c_j` if `cell[i][j]` is not hole. Now, I've to find maximum flow in this bipartite graph while making sure flow from each row is same as flow from each column. I doubt if this will be equal to minimum among flows from rows/to columns in case of maximum bipartite matching. Can this statement be proved/disproved? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could clearly set it up as a problem in integer linear programming - but of course there is no guarantee that the resulting integer linear program is tractable.

Comment: If you are prepared to try every possible number of rooks from i=1..N then for your maximum flow approach you can set the maximum flow into each row and the maximum flow out of each column, which gives you a maximum flow problem without any non-standard constraints. Also, the solution to the maximum flow problem without any input or output capacities gives you an upper bound to the number of rooks in a column.

Comment: @mcdowella Trying every possible number of rooks from i=1..N is a nice idea. We can even binary search over the answer, reducing number of checks from N to log(N). Can it be reduced further?

Comment: sorry that's the best that I can do. In fact it wasn't even obvious to me that if there is a solution for some particular number of roots there will necessarily be a solution for every lesser number of rooks although I believe now that you are correct and there is.